# How to redirect desktop users

Tags: apache, redirect

I would like to stop access to my website which is hybrid app (webview) from any desktop device.

Not sure which user-agents I need to redirect.

My Rewrite rules so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} |
RewriteRule .* http://expamle.com/app [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's this [site](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) that offers redirection solutions for mobile, you could try using that and negate it or use it as an "if-else", something like

```
RewriteCond ... # (get them from that site) if mobile 
RewriteRule ".?" "-" [S=1] # skip next rule, no rewrite is done here
RewriteRule .* http://expamle.com/app [R]
```

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPad|iPhone|android
RewriteRule .* http://...co.uk/app [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/desktop/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Windows\ NT.+Touch [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ NT\ 6|Macintosh|Ubuntu|Linux\ (x86_64|i686)|CrOS [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://....co.uk [R] 
This is workig for everthing but ipad and iphone ,getting stuck in a loop? any advice

Comment: _You will almost always want to use [R] in conjunction with [L] (that is, use [R,L]) because on its own,...passes ...  to the next rule in the ruleset_. Also if you're redirecting on the same server/URL ... might be a good idea to add something like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app/.*$ ` on the first block of directives

Comment: Excellent, Many thanks for your help. Made the changes you subjected and its working now.